# model value displays null when [FromForm] is posted with image file in web api controller

Tags: asp.net, image, postman, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-webapi

> My API is as below. I am trying to post model value wth image file using postman. But, model value did not bind. How to post json data with image file using POSTMAN?

```
[HttpPost]
   [Route("api/images_upload")]
   public IActionResult UploadImages([FromForm] Chapter chapter,IFormFile file)
   {
       try
       {

           var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
           var absoluteFileName = fileName.Replace(fileName, Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
           var extension = Path.GetExtension(fileName);
           var fullFileName = string.Concat(absoluteFileName, extension);

           var physicalPath = Path.Combine(HostingEnvironment.WebRootPath, "images", fullFileName);

           file.CopyTo(new FileStream(physicalPath, FileMode.Create));
           return Content("Images Uploaded");
       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {
           throw ex;
       }

   }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For posting `Chapter` and `IFormFile file`, you could try to post with `form-data` in PostMan.

For posting `IFormFile`, you could not pass it through `application/json` content type. And when posting `form-data`, you should not add `Content-Type` as `application/json`, otherwise, the .net core will try `JsonFormatter` to bind the request body to model instead of `FromForm`, then `chapter` will be null.

Here is a working PostMan demo.

[image]

Note, there is no `Content-Type` header.

Answer (score 0):

None of the above quite worked for me. But my issue was fixed by creating a new class for the type and then using the Bind attribute.

```
[Bind]
public class FileApplication
{
    public IFormFile Files { get; set; }
    public long Id { get; set; }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding content type for the file if you know content in the file of specific type like application/pdf.

For me After adding content-type column in form data in postman and adding content-type of the file like application/xml worked